# When will the equality involving inner product of averages of vectors holds

Tags: sequences-and-series, inner-products

Let $\left\lbrace x_{i} \right\rbrace _{i=1}^{k}$ and $\left\lbrace y_{i} \right\rbrace _{i=1}^{k}$ be nonzeros sequences in real Hilbert space. Define
\begin{equation}
\widehat{x} := \dfrac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_{i} \qquad \textrm{ and } \qquad \widehat{y} := \dfrac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} y_{i} .
\end{equation}
I need to determine in which case 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \left\langle x_{i} - \widehat{x} , y_{i} - \widehat{y} \right\rangle = \dfrac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \left\langle x_{i} - \widehat{x} , y_{i} \right\rangle ,
\end{equation}
or in other words, when will
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \left\langle x_{i} - \widehat{x} , \widehat{y} \right\rangle = 0 .
\end{equation}
At first, I thought that the above relation always holds. But on a second thought, I do not think this would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \left\langle x_{i} - \widehat{x} , \widehat{y} \right\rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\left( \left\langle x_{i}  , \widehat{y} \right\rangle - \left\langle \widehat{x},\widehat{y} \right\rangle    \right)  
=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}  \left\langle x_{i}  , \widehat{y} \right\rangle -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \left\langle \widehat{x},\widehat{y} \right\rangle    $$
and both terms are equal to to $k\left\langle \widehat{x},\widehat{y} \right\rangle$.

Comment: by the definition of $k \widehat{x} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_{i}$ does it means that the equations always holds?